# Density of a random variable as a function of random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent and uniformly distributed on $(a,b)$. Find the density of $Z = |Y-X|$.

My solution is not the same as the textbook solution. I'm not sure why.

Here's what I did:

$$
\begin{align}
F_Z(z) & = P(|Y-X| \leq z) = P(-z \leq Y-X \leq z) = P(X-z \leq Y \leq X + z) \\[8pt]
& = \int_0^z \int_0^{x+z} \frac{1}{(b-a)^2} \mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{d}x  + \int_z^{1-z} \int_{x-z}^{x+z}  \frac{1}{(b-a)^2} \mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{1-z}^1 \int_{x-z}^1  \frac{1}{(b-a)^2} \mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{d}x \\[8pt]
&  = \frac{2z - 2z^2 -½}{(b-a)^2}
\end{align}
$$

if $0 < z < (b-a)/2$.

$$F_Z(z) = \int_0^{1-z} \int_0^{x+z} \frac{1}{(b-a)^2} \mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{d}x  + \int_{1-z}^z \int_0^1  \frac{1}{(b-a)^2} \mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{d}x + \int_z^1 \int_{x-z}^1  \frac{1}{(b-a)^2} \mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{d}x $$

if $(b-a)/2 \leq z < 2$.

The textbook solution is $f_Z(z) = \frac{2}{b-a} \left(1 - \frac{z}{b-a}\right)$.

Here are the figures. The first one is for $0 < z < (b-a)/2$; the second one, $(b-a)/2 \leq z < 2$.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your densities, say $(2z - 2z^2 -½)/(b-a)^2$ cannot be correct since, if $z$, $a$ and $b$ were lengthes, they would add lengthes to areas to numbers with no dimension. (Additionally, they take *negative* values, not a good sign for densities.)

Comment: It is conventional to use the lower-case $f$, as in $f_Z(z)$, for the _densisty_, and the capital $F$, as in $F_Z(z)$, for the cumulative distribution function $z\mapsto\Pr(|Y-X|\le z)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Did Do you have any suggestion on how solve the problem?

Comment: I don't understand the limits of integration. For example in the first integral of the first displayed line, why does $y$ start at $0$? One should perhaps draw a picture of the square on which the joint density lives, in order to get the right limits or solve the problem geometrically.

Comment: Sure, even **two**: either track the computation mistakes in your proof, or draw a picture of the square $(a,b)\times(a,b)$ where $(X,Y)$ lives and compute the area of the part $|x-y|\leqslant z$ of this square.

Comment: Oh I get it now. I drew the figures and use interval (0,1) as an example and forgot to replace it with (a,b). Thanks all.